# Downcasting in C++ with virtual base class

Tags: c++

Consider the scenario:

```
class Base { };

class Derived: public virtual Base {};

int main(void) {
    Derived * d = new Derived();

    Base * b = d;

    Derived * x = static_cast<Derived*>(b); // Probably impossible

    delete x;
}
```

Here the downcast from pointer to Base to pointer to Derived is giving a compilation error saying "cannot convert since base is virtual". I cannot dynamic cast here since Base is not a polymorphic type. My questions are:

1. Is this simply impossible to do?
2. How does the C++ standard (11 or 14) state that this is impossible?

If it is impossible, I want to understand why. I know that virtual methods are implemented via vptr table, but how are virtual base classes implemented? I also know that the C++ standard does not define implementation, but I would like to understand the implementation of something common like gcc none the less. So the question is:

3. What is the underlying implementation of a standard compiler like gcc which makes this feature impossible?

This is probably a fairly simple question for all the C++ gurus out there, but I just could not find anything concrete after google-ing for half an hour. Please feel free to duplicate, down-vote etc if this is already covered.

Comment: If you have _one_ virtual base class ... there's nothing actually virtual about it.  Virtual base classes only make a difference if you've got a "diamond" pattern:  Your class `D` derives from two classes, `A1` and `A2`, and _each_ of those derives from `B`.  If they just plain derive from `B` your class `D` has _two_ separate copies of `B`.  When that is _not_ what you want you must have `A1` and `A2` _virtually_ derive from `B`: Then your `D` only has _one_ copy of `B`, and thus the compiler has to do some work to get that to happen.

Comment: Now, to get your derived class to work correctly _in any case_ you typically have to have your _base_ classes - i.e., your _most base_ classes - all have virtual destructors.  You can look that up to see why, but basically you can't correctly destruct the derived classes through a base pointer without that.  And as soon as your _most base_ classes have a virtual destructor _then_ you can use _dynamic_cast_ to downcast.  And this has _nothing_ to do with _virtual_ base classes: it applies to _all_ class hierarchies.

Comment: (I don't have time to make an answer with proper links that you're asking for, therefore I'm violating SO rules to answer in comments.  But if anyone else wants to take up the gauntlet and start with this ... feel free!)

Comment: (One last comment:  Do not be confused.  Virtual methods have nothing to do with virtual base classes, and vice versa.  They're orthogonal concepts.  The _implementation_ uses shared data structures built by the compiler, but the concepts are separate.)

Comment: virtual non-polymprphic base? why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this simply impossible to do?

Yes.

> How does the C++ standard (11 or 14) state that this is impossible?

It is stated under the requirements of `static_cast`.

> **[expr.static.cast]** - emphasis mine
>
> [11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.static.cast#11) A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type,
>   can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D,” where D is a
>   class derived (Clause [class.derived]) from B, if a valid standard
>   conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists ([conv.ptr]),
>   cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than,
>   cv1, **and B is neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of
>   a virtual base class of D**.

As you can see, `Base` cannot be virtual or even a non-virtual base of another virtual base.

> What is the underlying implementation of a standard compiler like gcc which makes this feature impossible?

Virtual inheritance is a mechanism that allows the same `Base` subobject to be shared between different intermediate base classes. For instance, if you were to add:

```
class Derived2: public virtual Base {};
class MostDerived: public Derived, public Derived2 {};
```

Then `MostDerived` will have a sub-object of type `Derived` and type `Derived2`, but unlike regular inheritance, they won't each have their own `Base` sub-object (thus 2 `Base` sub-objects in `MostDerived`). Instead there will be only one `Base` sub-object, and both `Derived` and `Derived2` will refer to it.

This is commonly accomplished by `Derived` and `Derived2` accessing the `Base` indirectly through some pointer. They cannot rely on it being placed inside themselves at a certain offset. The location of their `Base` is determined by the **most derived object**. So if you have a `Base*`, there is no one well-determined way to go to the `Derived` object that refers to it.

In the case of non-virtual inheritance, the `Base` would be located at a place known to the compiler relative to the `Derived` sub-object that contains it fully. So the compiler could do the pointer arithmetic required to obtain the `Derived` sub-object. But in your case, it cannot, because there is no guarantee of relative placement. The access is (generally) indirect.

---

You didn't ask, but I might as well address that too. The reason a `dynamic_cast` works for polymorphic classes, is that polymorphic classes can have RTTI associated with them in their vtable (if they have one). And because that `Base*` will point to the vtable of `MostDerived` (or `Derived`), the `dynamic_cast` mechanism can leverage information written in that table to figure out how to obtain the sub-object it needs. The table can contain all the offset information it needs to get from any one sub-object to any other sub-object. And because it is the table of the most derived object (at run-time), that information is fixed and reliable.

Comment: The case might have been stronger if `Derived2` inherited from `Derived` itself. Then, an instance of `MostDerived` would have two instances of `Derived` but only one instance of `Base`.

Comment: @jxh - You don't need such a complicated example, the location is unknown statically even in the absence of ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, your answer explained why relative offset wouldn't work. But ambiguity would also explain why table based offsets wouldn't work. Answer already upvoted BTW.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica said "The location of their Base is determined by the most derived object. " So, why if you know that you downcast to the exact class of the instance, as in the example provided ?

Comment: @ArnaudMégret - "if you know" the compiler has no way of knowing in the general case, and it isn't worth the hassle trying to prove (because outside code may still be deriving further). It will let you do it via rtti, and that really is good enough.

Comment: As I understand, RTTI is only available in case of polymorphism and it might be a bit more costly because the processor must read it and find the memory offset depending on the read value. It would be some kind of oprimization if one could to tell the compiler "don't bother to look at the RTTI. In that precise case, I know the exact class of the object.